# Outlook folders not appearing in GMAIL IMAP

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

I have a GMAIL account in Outlook that is IMAP.

I have created folders in the inbox that do not reflect in gmail.

I have several gmail accounts that are IMAP. This is the only one that is a problem.

I have checked subscriptions and they are marked.

At a loss here. Any help appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Gmail doesn't have folders, only labels. We need more information to understand the problem.

Comment: But they appear in gmail as labels and have a similar structure. So in my other accounts if I create a folder in OST there is one created in gmail. This is not the case with this account. The emails in these folder exist but no label is created.

Comment: In my one gmail account, I created a folder called "New Folder"

Shorty there after in gmail a label was created "INBOX/New Folder"

If I do this in the account in question, no label is created.

Comment: Perhaps you could remove and add again the account?

Comment: @harrymc, I am trying to avoid resorting all of the emails. Locally they are in the folders. On the server they are in ALL MAIL. Thank you. It may be my last resort

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, the labels can be synchronized normally if I set the Outgoing server as 587 and set the type of the encryption connection as STARTTLS when configuring the account as IMAP on outlook client.
[image]

But if I set Outgoing server as 587 and set the type of the encryption connection as SSL/TSL, the result is the same as the problem you described.

Please check your settings and set them as shown in the figure above to check if your problem would be solved. (Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles…>>double click the profile which the account is configured>Email Account>double click the account>More Settings…>under Advanced tab)

Comment: Thank you for responding.

I am working with Outlook 2013 so I don't believe STARTTLS is available. 

This account and the two other GMAIL accounts are set to 587 and TLS.

I just tested creating a folder in the other two accounts. By the time I logged into gmail via Chrome, the corresponding labels .

I have also ran scanpst on the OST. found errors but no joy.

Thanks again.

Comment: Also on another computer, using that particular email account, folders can be created and corresponding label appear on the server

Comment: If I go to define send and receive groups, the sub folders have no check boxes next to them unlike the ones in other accounts

Comment: Considering that you have encountered an error while running SCANPST tool, and the labels can be synchronized when the specific account is configured on the client of another computer, it may be that there is something wrong with your data file. It is recommended that you could try to create a new profile(control panel>mail>show profile>new) and add the account for testing to check if the labels can be synchronized normally.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting Auto in encryption connection which set the port to 25. Then the folders/labels instantly synchronized in Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Outlook 2013. My solution was to move the custom IMAP folders into Personal Folders temporarily. Afterwards I created an IMAP folder by hand in Outlook, and verified that it appeared in Gmail.

It seems that possibly dragging folders from another account into a newly-added Gmail account might cause Outlook to not create a label successfully, and the process hangs invisibly in the background until the offending folder is removed from Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem of sub folders (or Labels) not appearing in Outlook on my MacOS Outlook 365 account.
I solved it in a very crude way by using Gmail in Chrome and changing the sub folder (label names) so that this change forced a synch.  The folders now appear in Outlook.
But surely the issue needs better investigation by MicroSoft!